# What exactly is the short echo tag <?= ?>? How does it work? What is its advantage over <?php ?> tag?

Tags: php, tags, echo

I was reading PHP manual.

I came across following sentence in the manual **"There is also the short echo tag , which is always available in PHP 5.4.0 and later".**

I didn't understand what does it mean?

I tried to execute following code with the so called **short echo tag**  as the manual says it's always available in **PHP 5.4.0 and later**. I'm using **PHP 7.1.10**.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>This is going to be ignored by PHP and displayed by the browser.</p>
        <?= echo 'While this is going to be parsed.'; ?>
        <p>This will also be ignored by PHP and displayed by the browser.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

I received following error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\hello.php on line 9
```

If it's always available then why I got this error?

I've three questions regarding this short echo tag `<?= ?>`

- What exactly is the short echo tag `<?= ?>` ?
- How does it work?
- What is its advantage over `<?php ?>` tag?
- What is the necessary of it as there is already `<?php ?>` tag present?

Thanks.

Comment: `<?='abc'?>` == `<?php echo 'abc'; ?>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: *"I tried to execute following code with the so called short echo tag **as the manual says** it's always available in PHP 5.4.0 and later"* - Nowhere did I see in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php the use or an example showing `<?= echo`.

Comment: Remove the 'echo' bit an you should be fine. Like this: <?= 'While this is going to be parsed.'; ?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If it's always available then why I got this error?

Because you put an `echo` statement after the `<?=`. You should just put the expression you want to echo.

The error said "unexpected echo", it isn't directly related to the short tags.

> What exactly is the short echo tag `<?= ?>` ?

A tag to echo content.

> How does it work?

It echos whatever expression you put inside it

> What is its advantage over `<?php ?>` tag?

It is shorter

> What is the necessary of it as there is already `<?php ?>` tag present?

It isn't necessary. It is convenient.  Programming languages are there to make life easier for programmers. If they included only things that were necessary then we'd all be programming using assembly language.

Answer (score 2):

**WHY ?**

Why do you write `Dr.` for `doctor`. Just to make it smaller. Similarly, `<?= ... ?>` is the same as `<?php echo ... ?>` but just a smaller and neater form.

Main advantage is **Readability**. It makes the code a lot easier to read.

**And, fixing your error:**

No need to use `echo` when using the short echo tags

```
<?= 'While this is going to be parsed.' ?>
```

not

```
<?= echo 'While this is going to be parsed.'; ?>
```

**Update:**

just came across this flow chart, thought it might help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of `<?=` over `<?php echo` is just the size difference it makes your code more readable. Thus a bit better.

For example say you have the variable `$hello`, you want to simply print it, you can use:

```
<?=$hello;?>
```

OR

```
<?php echo $hello; ?>
```

OR

```
<?php print_r($hello); ?>
```

Or even

```
<?php var_dump($hello); ?>
```

Now, you tell me, which one is easier to read and would be easier to fit in a legible piece of code? It's just less code you have to write.

Answer (score 0):

first of all

`<?= ?>` is shorthand of `<?php echo ?>`

so that will be `<?= 'While this is going to be parsed.'; ?>`

note that if you want to use that short hand, you have to inform your php.ini

```
short_open_tag = On
```

That shorthand is mostly used in template or for fast writing. example:

`<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>` will be easier if you write `<h1><?= $title; ?></h1>`